# EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod @react-native-community iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, react-native-cli

I am using React v16.8.6 and react-native v0.59.6. iOS.

While typing **react-native --version** or anything prefix with **react-native**, it is showing the following error.

```
internal/fs/utils.js:220
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel'
    at Object.chmodSync (fs.js:1104:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/copyToClipBoard.js:50:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/middleware/copyToClipBoardMiddleware.js:8:47)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30) {
  errno: -1,
  syscall: 'chmod',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel'
}
```

I cleaned the project. Restarted it.

Deleted the npm package and reinstalled it.

Tried **npm install -g react-native-cli**.

I have **react-native-community/cli version 1.12.0** in package.lock.json dependancies.

I don't have any clue about what to do. I cannot link any libraries and other stuff requiring react-native keywords.

Moreover,
If I run it with `sudo` like `sudo react-native --version`, it is giving like below mentioned.

```
warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-google-sign in: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin
  - react-native-video: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#readme
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
3.0.4
```

Please suggest some guidance regarding the same.

Thanks.

Comment: are you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install` this will solve your problem.

It's because of the compatibility issues of the dependent packages. Try to move/remove package-lock.json from the dir and do the installation again.

Comment: Any explanation why ?

Comment: It's because of the compatibility issues of the dependent packages. Try to move/remove **package-lock.json** from the dir and do the installation again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Removing `node_modules` and installing them again fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

removing node_modules and running **npm i** resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your Mac.

I do not know why this solution works.

Comment: Can we also just not use React Native? It's not very good.

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall react-native module from node_modules and install it again.

sudo npm uninstall react-native
sudo npm install react-native